# Should std::function assignment ignore return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, c++14

Is the code below valid C++ according to the C++11 or C++14 standard?

```
#include <functional>

int ReturnInt()
{
  return 5;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  std::function< void () > BoundType = ReturnInt;
  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine with the latest cygwin versions of gcc (4.8.3) and clang (4.3.2) but not with Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio November 2013 CTP or the Visual Studio 14 preview. It also compiles on all platforms if std::function is changed to boost::function.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866779/function-pointers-and-return-type-conversions) other stack overflow question that suggests it should work.

Comment: Yeah that looks like that is the same issue. I did try to search for it before posting but obviously not hard enough, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is undefined behavior in C++11, and ill-formed in C++14.  C++14 adds this *Remark* to the specification of this constructor:

> *Remarks*: These constructors shall not participate in overload
>   resolution unless `f` is Callable (20.9.11.2) for argument types
>   `ArgTypes...` and return type `R`.

Callable is defined in [func.wrap.func]/p2:

> A callable object `f` of type `F` is *Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes`
>   and return type `R` if the expression *INVOKE* `(f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5), is well formed (20.9.2).

For this *INVOKE* to be well formed, the return type of *INVOKE* without the `R` must be implicitly convertible to `R` ([func.require]/p2).

In C++11 these statements were under a *Requries* clause, which means it is up to the client to get them right, and if the client fails, anything can happen, including successful compilation.

This was changed by [LWG 2132](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2132).

Comment: @BЈовић: The link is right at the end of my answer (you may need to refresh).  LWG 2132.

Comment: This is a defect in the standard as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Yakk: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: [it is worse than I thought](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395605/is-it-illegal-to-invoke-a-stdfunctionvoidargs-under-the-standard) (and someone else already submitted the bug for the worst problem, which may resolve this one)

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` in C++11 and 14 does not have the behavior you desire.

It also fails to SFINAE detect bad overloads.

We can wrap it in a different type that both has the behavior you desire (`void` discarding return) and has SFINAE bad overload detection while we are at it as follows:

```
template<class Sig>
struct checked_function;

template<class R, class... Args>
struct checked_function<R(Args...)>:std::function<R(Args...)> {
  using function = std::function<R(Args...)>;
  checked_function(std::nullptr_t):function() {}
  checked_function():function() {}
  template<class F, class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , R
    >::value
  >::type>
  checked_function( F&& f ):function( std::forward<F>(f) ) {}

  template<class F, class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , R
    >::value
  >::type>
  checked_function& operator=( F&& f ) { return function::operator=( std::forward<F>(f) ); }

  checked_function& operator=( checked_function const& o ) = default;
  checked_function& operator=( checked_function && o ) = default;
  checked_function( checked_function const& o ) = default;
  checked_function( checked_function && o ) = default;
};

template<class... Args>
struct checked_function<void(Args...)>:std::function<void(Args...)> {
  using function = std::function<void(Args...)>;
  checked_function(std::nullptr_t):function() {}
  checked_function():function() {}
  template<class F, class=typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , void
    >::value
  >::type>
  checked_function( F&& f, int*unused=nullptr ):function( std::forward<F>(f) ) {}

  template<class F>
  static auto wrap(F&& f){
    return [f_=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args){
      f_( std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... );
    };
  }
  template<class F, class=typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , void
    >::value
  >::type>
  checked_function( F&& f, void*unused=nullptr ):
    function( wrap(std::forward<F>(f)) ) {}

   template<class F>
  typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , void
    >::value,
    checked_function&
  >::type operator=( F&& f ) { return function::operator=( wrap(std::forward<F>(f)) ); }

  template<class F>
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
      typename std::result_of< F(Args...) >::type
      , void
    >::value,
    checked_function&
  >::type operator=( F&& f ) { return function::operator=( std::forward<F>(f) ); }

  checked_function& operator=( checked_function const& o ) = default;
  checked_function& operator=( checked_function && o ) = default;
  checked_function( checked_function const& o ) = default;
  checked_function( checked_function && o ) = default;
};
```

It now compiles in C++14 (not in C++11, due to `wrap`: `wrap` can be replaced at point of call with a copy of its own body, so...).  Could probably reduce boilerplate by a bunch.

It uses some C++14 features (move-into-lambda to be precise in `wrap` -- you can do away with that by adding more boilerplate).

Not run yet.

Comment: Would you expect it to work like this `checked_function< void() > BoundType = &ReturnInt;`? I fixed up a few typos and things but it still won't compile http://pastebin.com/VdPqZCzx.

I think the std::is_same in the void specialisation is wrong, also you'd need to write the operator() overload that does actually ignore the return type.

Comment: @fun4jimmy You deleted the constructor that `wrap`s non-`void` returning functions, so naturally it won't be able to `wrap` them.  I edited the post with one that compiles.

Comment: Ah sorry I thought that was a copy and paste section you missed, my bad. That works, awesome thanks.