# Is it illegal to invoke a std::function<void(Args...)> under the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std-function, c++14

All quotes are from [N3797](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf).

**4/3 [conv]**

> An expression
>   e
>   can be
>   implicitly converted
>   to a type
>   T
>   if and only if the declaration
>   T t=e;
>   is well-formed,
>   for some invented temporary variable
>   t

This implies no expression can be implicitly converted to `void`, as `void t=e` is illegal for all expressions `e`.  This is even true if `e` is an expression of type `void`, such as `void(3)`.

So an expression of type `void` cannot be implicitly converted to `void`.

Which leads us to:

**20.9.2/2 Requirements [func.require]**

> Define
>   INVOKE
>   (f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)
>   as
>   INVOKE
>   (f, t1, t2, ..., tN)
>   implicitly converted to
>   R
>   .

In short, `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` is never valid when `R` is `void`, as nothing (including `void`) can be implicitly converted to `void`.

As a result of this, all `std::function<void(Args...)>` have the property `!*this` and thus cannot be called, as the only constructors that do not have `!*this` as a postcondition (or do not copy such state from another `function` of the same type) require `Callable` of one of the parameters.

**20.9.11.2/7 Class template
function
[func.wrap.func]**

> Requires:
>   F
>   shall be
>   CopyConstructible
>   .
>   f
>   shall be Callable (
>   20.9.11.2
>   ) for argument types
>   ArgTypes
>   and return type
>   R
>   . The copy constructor and destructor of
>   A
>   shall not throw exceptions.

**20.9.11.2/2 Class template
function
[func.wrap.func]**

> A callable object
>   f
>   of type
>   F
>   is
>   Callable
>   for argument types
>   ArgTypes
>   and return type
>   R
>   if the expres-
>   sion
>   INVOKE
>   (f, declval()..., R)
>   , considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause
>   5
>   ), is well
>   formed (
>   20.9.2
>   ).

As demonstrated above, there are no `Callable` expressions for `std::function<void(Args...)>`.

If somehow such a `std::function<void(Args...)>` where found, invoking `operator()` would be ill formed:

**invocation [func.wrap.func.inv]**

> Effects:
>   INVOKE
>   (f, std::forward(args)..., R)
>   (
>   20.9.2
>   ), where
>   f
>   is the target ob-
>   ject (
>   20.9.1
>   ) of
>   *this
>   .

as `INVOKE(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., void)` is ill formed for all arguments and `f`.

Is this line of reasoning sound?

Comment: Sounds like a defect in the standard.

Comment: Interestingly `is_convertible<void, void>::value` is `true`

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, that type trait is specified ([meta.rel]/p4) in a rather convoluted manner to "give well defined results for reference types, void types, array types, and function types."

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, `declval` uses `add_rvalue_reference`, which is special-cased for `void`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is correct; I came to the same conclusion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/S9xdBpKpZMg/R3SL85z_e0AJ).

According to Daniel Kruegler, this issue [should appear on the library defect list subsequent to the next mailing](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/S9xdBpKpZMg/7rxL3NAY8u4J):

> A corresponding library issue has already been submitted, but is not 
>   yet visible in the issue list.

Hopefully once that becomes visible we'll also have a conclusive answer to whether it is allowable to construct a `std::function` with signature returning `void` passing a callable with signature returning non-void ([Using `std::function<void(...)>` to call non-void function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339829/using-stdfunctionvoid-to-call-non-void-function)).

---

Update: this was entered as [LWG 2420](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2420), which was resolved in favor of special-casing `void` return type to `static_cast` the result of the invoked function to `void`. This means that a callable returning non-`void` can be the target of a `std::function<void(...)>`. LWG2420 was applied as a post-publication correction to C++14; meanwhile, all compilers I'm aware of effectively apply this behavior as an extension in C++11 mode.