# Why does operator() change for std::function in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

The following code is supposedly illegal in C++14 but legal in C++17:

```
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int x = 1729;
    std::function<void (int&)> f(
        [](int& r) { return ++r; });
    f(x);
}
```

Don't bother testing it, you'll get inconsistent results making it difficult to suss whether it's a bug or intentional behavior. However, comparing two drafts (N4140 vs N4527, both can be found on github.com/cplusplus/draft), there's one significant difference in [func.wrap.func.inv]. Paragraph 2:

> Returns: Nothing if R is void, otherwise the return value of INVOKE (f, std::forward(args)..., R).

The above was removed between drafts. The implication is that the return value of the lambda is now **silently discarded**. This seems like a misfeature. Can anyone explain the reasoning?

Comment: [LWG 2420](http://wg21.link/lwg2420). That behavior was intended since the very beginning, and was only removed by accident.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. I was looking at library defects rather than language defects.

Comment: Is that supposed to say `return f(x);`?

Comment: @AlanStokes Nope. Why?

Comment: @AlanStokes `int main()` can be without a return value in C++, which defaults to returning 0. Also, `f` has return type `void` anyway, can't return that.

Comment: You can already bind a `void foo();` to a `std::function<void(int, int, int)> f` and calling `f(1,2,3)` will happily discard all the arguments, why should return values be any different?

Comment: @melak47 Wait, what? You can't do that (unless you are using `std::bind`, but that's a property of `std::bind`, not `std::function`).

Comment: Well I did say bind :)

Comment: OP, why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 21):

There was a [ridiculous defect in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25395605/1774667) about `std::function<void(Args...)>`.  By the wording of the standard, no (non-trivial)<sup>1</sup> use of `std::function<void(Args...)>` was legal, because nothing can be "implicitly converted to" `void` (not even `void`).

`void foo() {}  std::function<void()> f = foo;` was not legal in C++14.  Oops.

Some compilers took the bad wording that made `std::function<void(Args...)>` completely useless, and applied the logic only to passed-in callables where the return value was *not* `void`.  Then they concluded it was illegal to pass a function returning `int` to `std::function<void(Args...)>` (or any other non-`void` type).  They did not take it to the logical end and ban functions returning `void` as well (the `std::function` requirements make no special case for signatures that match exactly: the same logic applies.)

Other compilers just ignored the bad wording in the `void` return type case.

The defect was basically that the return type of the invocation expression has to be implicitly convertible-to the return type of the `std::function`'s signature (see link above for more details).  And under the standard, `void` cannot be implicitly converted to `void`<sup>2</sup>.

So the defect was resolved.  `std::function<void(Args...)>` now accepts anything that can be invoked with `Args...`, and discards the return value, as many existing compilers implemented.  I presume this is because (A) the restriction was not ever intended by the language designers, or (B) having a way for a `std::function` that discards return values was desired.

`std::function` has *never* required exact match of arguments or return values, just compatibility.  If the incoming arguments can implicitly convert-from the signature arguments, and the return type can implicitly convert-to the return type, it was happy.

And a function of type `int(int&)` is, under many intuitive definitions, compatible with the signature `void(int&)`, in that you can run it in a "void context".

---

<sup>1</sup> Basically, anything that makes `operator()` legal to call was not allowed.  You can create it, you can destroy it, you can test it (and know it is empty).  You cannot give it a function, even one that matches its signature exactly, or a function object or lambda.  Ridiculous.

<sup>2</sup> For `void` to be impliclty converted to `void` under the standard, it requires that the statement `void x = blah;`, where `blah` is an expression of type void, be valid; that statement is not valid, as you cannot create a variable of type `void`.