# Why doesn't function prevent construction from different return type?

Tags: c++

`std::function` allows you to do this:

```
std::function<void()> = []()->int{return 42;};
```

But not this:

```
std::function<void()> = [](int i)->int{return 42;};
```

Presumably because the return type is not part of a function's signature. But `std::function` is a class type that is given a return type and knows the return type of the function object it's constructed from. So there's a possibility of a compiler error here.

Why is there no compiler error?

Comment: Also your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper: It's not a duplicate of the first one, since the first one is about parameters, not return types differing.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is definitely a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9341064). The short of it is `int` is not implicitly convertible to `void` so we get undefined behavior.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper [Not any more](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420).

Comment: @user6412786: He's not asking if its well-defined behavior. He's asking why it isn't a *compile error*. That's a different question.

Answer (score 4):

There was a [bug in the C++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25395605/1774667) that made all `std::function<void(???)>` completely unusable.  Some compilers interpreted the bug to mean the return type of anything stored in such a `std::function` should be ignored, others that only void was compatible with such a `std::function`.

In the [defect resolution](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420) (via @t.c) it was fixed so that a `std::function<void(???)>` ignores the return type (and value) of the object stored.

Your compiler is using that interpretation, which is the current one.

Regardless, the arguments must be converted to from the arguments of the `std::function`.

In short, because the standard (revised) says so.

In practice, being able to discard return values is useful.  Mean while, you cannot invoke a function or callable object without data to invoke it.  It was decided that imperfect matching is ok (so if the arguments/return values convert, `std::function` is game).  And there you have it.