# What are the type conversion rules for parameters and return values of lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, type-conversion

I was recently surprised by the fact that lambdas can be assigned to `std::function`s with *slightly different* signatures. *Slightly different* meaning that return values of the lambda might be ignored when the `function` is specified to return `void`, or that the parameters might be references in the `function` but values in the lambda.

See [this example (ideone)](http://ideone.com/xXXvQz) where I highlighted what I would suspect to be incompatible. I would think that the return value isn't a problem since you can always call a function and ignore the return value, but the conversion from a reference to a value looks strange to me:

```
int main() {
    function<void(const int& i)> f;
    //       ^^^^ ^^^^^    ^
    f = [](int i) -> int { cout<<i<<endl; return i; };
    //     ^^^    ^^^^^^
    f(2);
    return 0;
}
```

The minor question is: Why does this code compile and work? The major question is: What are the general rules for type conversion of lambda parameters and return values when used together with `std::function`?

Comment: Also: Is there a specific term for what I am describing here, or is *type conversion* correct?

Comment: That looks a bit like covariance and contravariance, but I think these terms are only used between base and derived classes in OO.

Comment: I don't get the issue. If you have a function with signature `void(const int& i)`, can you forward in its body to a function with signature `int(int)`? Yes. You are not violating cv qualifiers (well, you are copying the value, so...) and you can freely discard the returned value. The opposite would have been wrong instead and it doesn't work indeed. So, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Allowing a non-void function to be stored in `std::function<void(blah)>` is something GCC always supported, and is now required, see http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420

Comment: _"The major question is: What are the general rules for type conversion of lambda parameters and return values?"_ No, your question is about using lambdas with `std::function`, which is not the same as the general rules about lambda return types.

Comment: And in fact it's not specific to lambdas at all, since exactly the same rules apply for normal functions stored in `std::function`. Normal functions have parameters and return types too, and they can also undergo conversions when called via `std::function`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Right; I was surprised because you can't do the same for function pointers, or when overloading functions in derived classes. So it is not immediately obvious that the rules for function calls apply, not rules similar to overloading etc.

Comment: And that's because `std::function` is not a function pointer, and is not a virtual override. It wraps a callable, adding a level of indirection, and conversions can take place in that level of indirection. See my answer for a direct analogy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can [assign a lambda to a function object](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#21) of type `std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>` when the lambda is [*Lvalue-Callable*](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func#2) for that signature. In turn, *Lvalue-Callable* is defined in terms of the [*INVOKE* operation](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#1), which here means that the lambda has to be callable when it is an lvalue and all its arguments are values of the required types and value categories (as if each argument was the result of calling a nullary function with that argument type as the return type in its signature).

That is, if you give your lambda an id so that we can refer to its type,

```
auto l = [](int i) -> int { cout<<i<<endl; return i; };
```

To assign it to a `function<void(const int&)>`, the expression

```
static_cast<void>(std::declval<decltype(l)&>()(std::declval<const int&>()))
```

must be well-formed.

The result of `std::declval<const int&>()` is an lvalue reference to `const int`, but there's no problem binding that to the `int` argument, since this is just the [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#1), which is [considered an exact match](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#tab:over.conversions) for the purposes of overload resolution:

```
return l(static_cast<int const&>(int{}));
```

As you've observed, return values are discarded [if the function object signature has return type `void`](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#2); otherwise, the return types have to be implicitly convertible. As Jonathan Wakely points out, C++11 had unsatisfactory behavior on this ([Using `std::function<void(...)>` to call non-void function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339829/using-stdfunctionvoid-to-call-non-void-function?noredirect=1&lq=1); [Is it illegal to invoke a std::function<void(Args...)> under the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395605/is-it-illegal-to-invoke-a-stdfunctionvoidargs-under-the-standard)), but it's been fixed since, in [LWG 2420](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420); the resolution was applied as a post-publication fix to C++14. Most modern C++ compiler will provide the C++14 behavior (as amended) as an extension, even in C++11 mode.

Comment: @skypjack that's the special case for `void` return types, yes (since you can't implicity convert a value to `void`). But I think the OP is more concerned with the behavior of argument conversions and where those are OK.

Comment: It makes sense. I'd just put in evidence what's the specific case, that's all. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack OK, I see your point. I've added the link to the last paragraph.

Comment: N.B. the question is marked C++11 and you're linking to a working draft of what will become C++17, quoting text that changed in 2015 (see [LWG 2420](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420)). That's worth calling out, since eel.is/c++draft is **not** the standard.

Comment: `declval<T>()` can be an xvalue, an lvalue, or (in exactly four cases) a prvalue. There is no such thing as a "prvalue of type `const int&`"; `declval<const int&>()` is an lvalue of type `const int`.

Comment: @T.C. you're completely correct; I was abusing terminology. Fixed, hopefully.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operator is defined to have the effect:

```
function(std::forward<F>(f)).swap(*this);
```

(*14882:2011 20.8.11.2.1 par. 18*)

The constructor that this references,

```
template <class F> function(F f);
```

requires:

> `F` shall be `CopyConstructible`. `f` shall be `Callable` (20.8.11.2) for argument type `ArgTypes` and return type `R`.

where `Callable` is defined as follows:

> A callable object `f` of type `F` is `Callable` for argument types `ArgTypes` and return type `R` if the expression `INVOKE(f, declval<ArgTypes>()..., R)`, considered as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), is well formed (20.8.2).

`INVOKE`, in turn, is [defined as](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#2):

> 1. Define INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) as follows:
>
>    - ... *cases for handling member functions omitted here* ...
>    - `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.
> 2. Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` as `static_cast<void>(INVOKE(f,
>      t1, t2, ..., tN))` if `R` is *cv* `void`, otherwise `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ...,
>      tN)` implicitly converted to `R`.

Since the `INVOKE` definition becomes a plain function call, in this case, the arguments can be [converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion): If your `std::function<void(const int&)>` accepts a `const int&` then it can be converted to an `int` for the call. The example below compiles with [`clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wconversion`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71eff7bcd5a7a20f):

```
int main() {
    std::function<void(const int& i)> f;
    f = [](int i) -> void { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
    f(2);
    return 0;
}
```

The return type (`void`) is handled by the `static_cast<void>` special-case for the `INVOKE` definition.

Note, however, that at the time of writing the following generates an error when compiled with [`clang++ -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++ -Wconversion -Wall`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dde24dce2c30b01), but not when compiled with [`clang++ -std=c++1z -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wconversion -Wall`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ea5eb38df0b3bd):

```
int main() {
    std::function<void(const int& i)> f;
    f = [](int i) -> int { std::cout << i << std::endl; return i;};
    f(2);
    return 0;
}
```

This is due to `libc++` implementing the behaviour as specified in C++14, rather than the [amended behaviour](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420) described above (thanks to @Jonathan Wakely for pointing this out). @Arunmu describes the `libstdc++` type trait responsible for the same thing in [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303083/3852968). In this regard, implementations may behave slightly differently when handling callables with `void` return types, depending on whether they implement C++11, 14, or something newer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I really like the fact that you quoted the standard, but @ecatmur's answer explains the same things in a slightly more concise way without sacrificing any of the major points so I accepted that one. But IMHO your answer would also deserve the same amount of upvotes :-)

Comment: The libc++ behaviour is not a bug, it because libc++ implements the C++14 rule, not the one in the working draft you linked to. The rule changed with http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2420

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for pointing this out. I've amended the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

> the conversion from a reference to a value looks strange to me

Why?

Does this look strange too?

```
int foo(int i) { return i; }

void bar(const int& ir) { foo(ir); }
```

This is exactly the same. A function taking an `int` by value gets called by another function, taking an `int` by const-reference.

Inside `bar` the variable `ir` gets copied, and the return value gets ignored. That's exactly what happens inside the `std::function<void(const int&)>` when it has a target with the signature `int(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to @ecatmur answer, g++/libstd++ just chose to ignore the return value of the `callable`, it's just as normal as one would do to ignore return value in regular code:

```
static void
_M_invoke(const _Any_data& __functor, _ArgTypes&&... __args)
{
   (*_Base::_M_get_pointer(__functor))(  // Gets the pointer to the callable
           std::forward<_ArgTypes>(__args)...);
}
```

The type trait which explicitly permits this in libstd++ is :

```
template<typename _From, typename _To>     
using __check_func_return_type = __or_<is_void<_To>, is_convertible<_From, _To>>;
```