# Is it safe to change a function pointers signature and call it to ignore the return type?

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

In our codebase we have callbacks that are stored using (eg. `std::function<void()>`). Sometimes we would like to bind a function with a different signature to the callback which can be done using bind. This is fine for different function parameters but trying to bind a function that returns something to a callback that is expecting a void return doesn't work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385876/should-stdfunction-assignment-ignore-return-type/25392559#25392559).

The simplest solution we have found is to cast the bound function's signature to a function with the same parameters but a void return type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int ReturnInt()
{
  std::cout << "ReturnInt" << std::endl;
  return 5;
}

struct Struct
{
  int ReturnInt()
  {
    std::cout << "Test::Func" << std::endl;
    return 30;
  }
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto IgnoreResult(ReturnType (*i_Func)(ArgumentTypes ...))
  -> void (*)(ArgumentTypes ...)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<void (*)(ArgumentTypes ...)>(i_Func);
}

template<typename ReturnType, typename ClassType, typename ... ArgumentTypes>
auto IgnoreResult(ReturnType (ClassType::*i_Func)(ArgumentTypes ...))
  -> void (ClassType::*)(ArgumentTypes ...)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<void (ClassType::*)(ArgumentTypes ...)>(i_Func);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::function<void ()> BoundType;

  Struct instance;
  BoundType = std::bind(IgnoreResult(&Struct::ReturnInt), &instance);
  BoundType();

  BoundType = std::bind(IgnoreResult(&ReturnInt));
  BoundType();

  return 0;
}
```

This has been tested with **Visual Studio 2013 November CTP**, **cygwin clang 3.4.2** and **cygwin gcc 4.8.3** and works on all platforms but calling a function pointer that has been cast to a different function signature is undefined behaviour.

I know that certain calling conventions could break it but as far as I could tell from the [**Microsoft** calling conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/984x0h58.aspx) the return type is passed via a register not via the stack. We are also never specifying different calling conventions and always use the defaults.

Assuming that the **gcc**, **clang** and **Microsoft** compilers don't change their behaviour, is this a safe method to use to ignore the return type of a function when binding a callback?

Comment: Why don't simply ignore the result after return, like `(void) ReturnInt();`?

Comment: So your question is whether it is safe to rely on undefined behavior ?

Comment: How about functions that return an object? The resulting object may be allocated by a caller and then constructed by a callee; if the caller is forced to ignore the declared result type of a callee, it won't allocate the object - what will then happen?

Comment: @CiaPan ignore it where? The callback has to have a void return type and in our codebase there are multiple functions with differing signatures all bound to the same callback.

Comment: @quantdev I guess my question is more like under what situations would this currently break with **gcc**, **clang** and **Microsoft** compilers. I know it's not safe to rely on undefined behaviour but this seems like the simplest solution for our current solution.

Comment: @CiaPan That situation doesn't happen in our code, I can see how that would be a problem if this were used in that way though.

Comment: Why not simply provide a wrapper that you can bind to that calls your functions? That way your code isn't filed with caveats, predictions, and uncertainties?

Comment: @HWalters That's definitely the most robust option. The definition of the wrapper is more involved than the definition of `IgnoreResult` above. We are also currently stuck using a compiler without variadic template support so will have to provide many overloads for differeing number of argument types. I thought I'd canvas some opinions before we decide which solution to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to change a function pointers signature and call it to ignore the return type?

No, it is not, c.f. the C++ standard, section § 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast]

> The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type (8.3.5) that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined.

Even if it does *appear* to work on a particular compiler/platform, nothing guarantees you that it *really* does (hidden side effects, stack corruption...).

You should consider a new design where this cast is not needed in the first place (hard to answer without more context)

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambdas:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int ReturnInt()
{
  std::cout << "ReturnInt" << std::endl;
  return 5;
}

struct Struct
{
  int ReturnInt()
  {
    std::cout << "Test::Func" << std::endl;
    return 30;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::function<void ()> BoundType;

  Struct instance;
  BoundType = [&instance] { instance.ReturnInt(); };
  BoundType();

  BoundType = [] { ReturnInt(); };
  BoundType();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might solve your problem using an approach similar to that [employed in libsigc++2](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net/libsigc2/docs/reference/html/group__hide.html#gd7e18e1edbbefe13216eb344bd522f0a) (via sigc::hide_return()).